# Deploy GitLab with Helm on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I need to deploy GitLab with Helm on Kubernetes.
I have the problem: PVC is Pending.

I see `volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default` in PVC description, but I set value `gitlabDataStorageClass: gluster-heketi` in values.yaml.
And I fine deploy simple nginx from article https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/examples/hello_world/README.md
Yes, I use distribute storage GlusterFS https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes

```
# kubectl get pvc
NAME                  STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS     AGE
gitlab1-gitlab-data   Pending                                                                                         19s
gitlab1-gitlab-etc    Pending                                                                                         19s
gitlab1-postgresql    Pending                                                                                         19s
gitlab1-redis         Pending                                                                                         19s
gluster1              Bound     pvc-922b5dc0-6372-11e8-8f10-4ccc6a60fcbe   5Gi        RWO            gluster-heketi   43m
```

Structure for single of pangings:

```
# kubectl get pvc gitlab1-gitlab-data -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
  creationTimestamp: 2018-05-29T19:43:18Z
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: gitlab1-gitlab-data
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "263950"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/gitlab1-gitlab-data
  uid: 8958d4f5-6378-11e8-8f10-4ccc6a60fcbe
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
status:
  phase: Pending
```

In describe I see:

```
# kubectl describe pvc gitlab1-gitlab-data
Name:          gitlab1-gitlab-data
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class=default
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----               ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  2m (x43 over 12m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

My values.yaml file:

```
# Default values for kubernetes-gitlab-demo.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.

# Required variables

# baseDomain is the top-most part of the domain. Subdomains will be generated
# for gitlab, mattermost, registry, and prometheus.
# Recommended to set up an A record on the DNS to *.your-domain.com to point to
# the baseIP
# e.g. *.your-domain.com.    A    300    baseIP
baseDomain: my-domain.com

# legoEmail is a valid email address used by Let's Encrypt. It does not have to
# be at the baseDomain.
legoEmail: my@mail.com

# Optional variables
# baseIP is an externally provisioned static IP address to use instead of the provisioned one.
#baseIP: 95.165.135.109
nameOverride: gitlab
# `ce` or `ee`
gitlab: ce
gitlabCEImage: gitlab/gitlab-ce:10.6.2-ce.0
gitlabEEImage: gitlab/gitlab-ee:10.6.2-ee.0
postgresPassword: NDl1ZjNtenMxcWR6NXZnbw==
initialSharedRunnersRegistrationToken: "tQtCbx5UZy_ByS7FyzUH"
mattermostAppSecret: NDl1ZjNtenMxcWR6NXZnbw==
mattermostAppUID: aadas
redisImage: redis:3.2.10
redisDedicatedStorage: true
redisStorageSize: 5Gi
redisAccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
postgresImage: postgres:9.6.5
# If you disable postgresDedicatedStorage, you should consider bumping up gitlabRailsStorageSize
postgresDedicatedStorage: true
postgresAccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
postgresStorageSize: 30Gi
gitlabDataAccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
#gitlabDataStorageSize: 30Gi
gitlabRegistryAccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
#gitlabRegistryStorageSize: 30Gi
gitlabConfigAccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
#gitlabConfigStorageSize: 1Gi
gitlabRunnerImage: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v10.6.0
# Valid values for provider are `gke` for Google Container Engine. Leaving it blank (or any othervalue) will disable fast disk options.
#provider: gke

# Gitlab pages
# The following 3 lines are needed to enable gitlab pages.
# pagesExternalScheme: http
# pagesExternalDomain: your-pages-domain.com
# pagesTlsSecret: gitlab-pages-tls # An optional reference to a tls secret to use in pages

## Storage Class Options
## If defined, volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: <storageClass>
## If not defined, but provider is gke, will use SSDs
## Otherwise default: volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
gitlabConfigStorageClass: gluster-heketi
gitlabDataStorageClass: gluster-heketi
gitlabRegistryStorageClass: gluster-heketi
postgresStorageClass: gluster-heketi
redisStorageClass: gluster-heketi

healthCheckToken: 'SXBAQichEJasbtDSygrD'
# Optional, for GitLab EE images only
#gitlabEELicense: base64-encoded-license

# Additional omnibus configuration,
# see https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html
# for possible configuration options
#omnibusConfigRuby: |
#  gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
#  gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.example.org"

gitlab-runner:
  checkInterval: 1
  # runnerRegistrationToken must equal initialSharedRunnersRegistrationToken
  runnerRegistrationToken: "tQtCbx5UZy_ByS7FyzUH"
  # resources:
  #   limits:
  #     memory: 500Mi
  #     cpu: 600m
  #   requests:
  #     memory: 500Mi
  #     cpu: 600m
  runners:
    privileged: true
    ## Build Container specific configuration
    ##
    # builds:
    #   cpuLimit: 200m
    #   memoryLimit: 256Mi
    #   cpuRequests: 100m
    #   memoryRequests: 128Mi

    ## Service Container specific configuration
    ##
    # services:
    #   cpuLimit: 200m
    #   memoryLimit: 256Mi
    #   cpuRequests: 100m
    #   memoryRequests: 128Mi

    ## Helper Container specific configuration
    ##
    # helpers:
    #   cpuLimit: 200m
    #   memoryLimit: 256Mi
    #   cpuRequests: 100m
    #   memoryRequests: 128Mi
```

You can see I have the StorageClass:

```
# kubectl get sc
NAME             PROVISIONER               AGE
gluster-heketi   kubernetes.io/glusterfs   48m
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a link to the actual helm you used, it's impossible for anyone to troubleshoot why the go-template isn't correctly consuming your `values.yaml`.

> I see `volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default` in PVC description, but I set value `gitlabDataStorageClass: gluster-heketi` in values.yaml

I can appreciate you set whatever you wanted in values.yaml, but as long as that `StorageClass` doesn't match any existing `StorageClass`, I'm not sure what positive thing will materialize from there. You can certainly try creating a `StorageClass` named `default` containing the same values as your `gluster-heketi` SC, or update the PVC to use the correct SC.

To be honest, this may be a bug in the helm chart, but until it is fixed (and/or we get the link to the chart to help you know how to adjust your yaml) if you want your GitLab to deploy, you will need to work around this bad situation manually.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was in call line, used other helm chart. Right call line for this values.yaml file: helm install --name gitlab1 -f values.yaml gitlab/gitlab-omnibus